# std::pair move not elided on definition?

Tags: c++, std-pair, visual-c++-2012, copy-elision

I noticed something very strange with Visual Studio 2012: Defining a pair object like so:

```
    auto objp = pair<int, LogMe>();
```

will *not* elide the copy/move of the pair in VC11, this call will print:

```
LogMe::LogMe - def.ctor!
LogMe::LogMe - move.ctor!
LogMe::~LogMe - dtor!
```

that is, a temporary pair *will* be created and then moved into the objp variable. (declaring it as `pair<...> obj;` only logs the default ctor)

I have cross checked with my LogMe test object alone:

```
cout << "# Construct Object via auto obj = ...\n";
auto obj = LogMe();

# Construct Object via auto obj = ...
LogMe::LogMe - def.ctor!
```

and here the assignment will be elided.

This seems to be specific to VC11, as [testing it in IDEOne](http://ideone.com/wXuU6o) (which uses gcc 4.8.1) shows that the extraneous move is elided always there.

**What's going on here?** *Not being able to rely on the initialization copy being elided makes me nervous.*

Note: Tests for release vs. debug version show the same result. (Which I would have expected, as copy-elision is performed independently of optimization flags in MSVC.)

---

Full sourcecode to test (See also the [ideone link](http://ideone.com/wXuU6o)):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct LogMe {
    std::string member;

    LogMe() {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << " - def.ctor!" << endl;
    }
    ~LogMe() {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << " - dtor!" << endl;
    }
    LogMe(LogMe const&) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << " - cpy.ctor!" << endl;
    }
    LogMe& operator=(LogMe const&) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << " - cpy.assign.op!" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    LogMe(LogMe&&) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << " - move.ctor!" << endl;
    }
    LogMe& operator=(LogMe&&) {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << " - move.assign.op!" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    {
        cout << "# Construct Object via auto obj = ...\n";
        auto obj = LogMe();
        cout << "# Construct pair<int, object> via auto objp = ...\n";
        auto objp = pair<int, LogMe>();
        cout << "# Construct pair<int, object> via pair objp2; ...\n";
        pair<int, LogMe> p2;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: I thought it might be that the `pair` constructor might be something like `pair( T&& = type1(), U&& = type2() )` -- ie, it might be creating the temporary in creating the single pair.  But that isn't the case -- there is an explicit trivial constructor.  The next question would be, are you doing this in debug?

Comment: @Yakk - see my note. debug vs release doesn't make a difference

Comment: Bah, missed that.  Does `auto` matter?

Comment: @Yakk - I think I saw that `auto` doesn't matter. I'll have to re-check once I get back to the machine with VC11.

Comment: Hmmm ... I tested this with VS2005 (without the moves and without the auto) and there the copy is also always elided.

Comment: as a crazy theory, maybe the `move` ctor confuses the vc11 elision optimizer?  Should be checkable.

Comment: @Yakk see my answer. Do you happen to have access to a VS2013 to check whether this is also present in the newest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears it is not the move ctor, nor the templated move ctor that is causing the problem, but  the presence of `enable_if<is_convertable<...` in the templated move ctor:

Testing with just an object, throwing `auto` and `pair` out of the test:

- OK, copy/move elided:

  ```
          cout << "# Construct Object: auto obj = LogMe();\n";
          LogMe obj = LogMe();

          LogMe(LogMe&&) {
              cout << __FUNCTION__ ...
          }
  ```

And, with a test like so:

```
    cout << "# Construct Object: LogMeTempl obj = LogMeTempl();\n";
    LogMeTempl obj = LogMeTempl();
    cout << "# Construct Object: LogMeTempl obj2;\n";
    LogMeTempl obj2;
```

- OK, copy move also elided:

  ```
  template<class Other>
  LogMeTempl(Other&& rhs
  //      , typename enable_if<is_convertible<Other, LogMeTempl>::value, void>::type ** = 0
  ) {
      cout << __FUNCTION__ << ...;
  }
  ```
- **Fail!** Move ctor invoked!

  ```
  template<class Other>
  LogMeTempl(Other&& rhs
          , typename enable_if<is_convertible<Other, LogMeTempl>::value, void>::type ** = 0
  ) {
      cout << __FUNCTION__ << ...;
  }
  ```

  And note that the enable_if can be reduced to `enable_if<true, void>::type** = 0` - if fact *any* additional defaulted parameter will do (e.g. `, int defaulted_param_on_move_ctor = 0` and it will still *prevent the move elision*).

  This also extends to a type with a copy-ctor only that has a default argument. It won't be elided either. A quick [cross-check with gcc](http://ideone.com/dBXckh) shows there doesn't seem to be any such problem there.

#### Short Answer

Types with defaulted arguments in their copy/move ctor *don't* have their initialization copy/move elided.

I have added a [bug on MS.connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805051/visual-c-11-vs-2012-copy-constructor-with-defaulted-second-argument-prevents-copy-elision) for this issue.

I have also added a test-case for (N)RVO [to IDEone](http://ideone.com/9XcO6w). Even without the default argument, *N*RVO seems to work better in gcc than VC++.

Comment: Neat!  So two problems: first, they have to use the hacky "default nullptr with contrived type" to enable SFINAE, and second because the elision optimization is blocked by additional default parameters (incorrectly, I think).  In C++11 (and in MSVC2013) they can use default template parameters in the ctor to do this without a default argument to the constructor.  I do not know if the MSVC2013 std C++ library has this improvement or not, but MSVC 2013 has compiler support for it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx